# Swift - label corner have different radius in tableviewcell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `tableView` cell with label.
I want to make the label with corner radius.
I know call the function like this:

```
label.layer.cornerRadius = 6
```

**Label with corner like this:**

[image: But I want to let three corners have] radius. 
So, I found the function.

```
func roundCorners(corners:UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
    let mask = CAShapeLayer()
    mask.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius)).cgPath
    layer.mask = mask
}
```

But I call this function the label disappear.
what wrong with my table view cell.

**Label disappear:**

[image]

My Code:

```
class ContentLabel:UILabel {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame:frame)
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        numberOfLines = 0
        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        let insets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: defaultContentPadding, left: defaultPadding, bottom: defaultContentPadding, right: defaultPadding)
        super.drawText(in: UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets))
    }

    class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

        var labelView:UILabel = { ()->UILabel in

            let label:UILabel = ContentLabel()
            label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            label.numberOfLines = 0
            label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byCharWrapping

            //label.layer.cornerRadius = 6  
            label.roundCorners(corners: [.topLeft,.topRight,.bottomLeft], radius: 6) 

            //What's wrong here!!!!!!!
            label.layer.masksToBounds = true
            return label
        }() 

        override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
            super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
            loadView()
        }

        func loadView() {
            contentView.addSubview(labelView)
        }

        override func layoutSubviews() {
            super.layoutSubviews()
            loadConstraints()
        }

        func loadConstraints() {
            let labelViewWidth:CGFloat = contentView.bounds.width*0.6
            labelView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: labelViewWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
            labelView.sizeToFit()

            let views = DictionaryOfInstanceVariables(self, objects: "labelView","icon")
            let metrics = ["padding":10]

            addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:[labelView]-padding-[icon]-padding-|", options: [], metrics: metrics, views: views))
        }
    }
```

I also try add the code in func `layoutSubviews()`, I successfully changed the corner, but when I scroll the `tableview`, the cell content disappeared, and it is very laggy to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

In storyboard apply constraint to label (w.r.to cell view,if you add it):

1. Top layout,
2. Leading,
3. horizontal spacing between image.